# Object passed dynamically to React component gives Typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm having a typescript error when trying to pass some dynamic values to a React component:

> Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

```
 import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import OurMissionList from "./SubModules/our-mission-list.component";

export const OurMission = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const section = t(`ourmission:section`, {
    returnObjects: true
  });

  console.log("section", section);

  return (
    <div className="our-mission content">
      <div className="section_info_wrapper container">
        <div className="info_text">
          <h2>{section.title}</h2>
          <p className="main_text"> {section.text}</p>
          <h3>{section.subtitle}</h3>
          <OurMissionList />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default OurMission;
```

The console.log of section is:

```
    {
    "title": "Deliver the best possible experience",
    "text": "To be the first choice of consumers and businesses by providing them with the best possible experience in telecommunications, entertainment, news media and culture, while being a leader in each of our lines of business.",
    "subtitle": "Key behaviours",
    "list": [
        {
            "name": "Performance",
            "pos": "Give your best effort at all times and dare to press for success."
        },
        {
            "name": "Innovation",
            "pos": "Come up with new ideas to solve the problems at hand and set us apart."
        },
        {
            "name": "Customer focus",
            "pos": "Be fully engaged, listen and demonstrate professionalism in order to anticipate and meet the wants and needs of our customers and business partners."
        },
        {
            "name": "Teamwork",
            "pos": "Provide mutual support and take advantage of each colleague’s strengths and ideas."
        },
        {
            "name": "Agility",
            "pos": "Be flexible and ready to adapt to circunstances."
        }
    ]
}
```

Anybody knows how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Is `section` actually an object or a JSON string?

Comment: What shows up when you try console.log(section.title)?

Comment: console.log(section.title);
Deliver the best possible experience

Comment: The original file `ourmission:section` is a JSON file

Comment: why you didn't declare an interface that shows what the Section is?

Comment: @barzin.A How I suppose to do that?

Comment: It's explained in their documentation, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll have to add a declaration file that extends some interfaces from the react_i18next package with types gathered from your translation JSON files for the `t` function to return the proper types.

This is explained here: https://react.i18next.com/latest/typescript#create-a-declaration-file

In short:

```
// react-i18next.d.ts
import 'react-i18next';
// import all namespaces (for the default language, only)
import ns1 from 'locales/en/ns1.json';
import ns2 from 'locales/en/ns2.json';

// react-i18next versions lower than 11.11.0
declare module 'react-i18next' {
  interface Resources {
    ns1: typeof ns1;
    ns2: typeof ns2;
  }
}

// react-i18next versions higher than 11.11.0
declare module 'react-i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    // custom namespace type if you changed it
    defaultNS: 'ns1';
    resources: {
      ns1: typeof ns1;
      ns2: typeof ns2;
    };
  }
}
```